# Is a function with optimal points at the endpoints convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

I know the maximum and minimum values of a bounded convex function occurs at the endpoints of the function. Is the converse holds:

If the maximum and minimum of a function are at the endpoints, is the function convex?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sinus between $-\pi/2$ and $9\pi/2$.